# Jackson: Serialize one variable into a sub-object without a wrapper class

Tags: java, json, jackson

I need to send JSON to a client and fulfill a contract with their already existing code.

I have a field in an object:

```java
public class FoodStores {
    //More variables
    private int wholemeal;
    ...
}
```

I need that single field to be serialized by jackson into the following format:

```
{
   //More JSON keys and values
   "bread": {
       "wholemeal": 5
   },
   ...
}
```

How can I accomplish this **without the use of a wrapper class?** The only approaches I've seen here involve using a wrapper class and naming it with `@JsonRootName`.

Comment: Other way is you need to write custom logic to serialize it, if you don't want to add that logic into your FoodStores class.